# Problem with form validation in template driven form

Tags: html, angular, forms, components

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I would like to create some custom components that are inspired by the components of HTML input. For example:

**CustomComponent.ts (typescript)**

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'custom-component',
    templateUrl: './custom-component.html',
    providers: [
       {
         provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
         multi: true,
         useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent)
       }
    ]
    })
    export class CustomComponent {

      @Input() name: string;
      @Input() isRequired: boolean;
    }
```

**CustomComponent.html (template)**

```
<input type="text"
   [attr.name]="name"
   [required] = "isRequired"
/>
```

I have this problem. Suppose we use my component in this template:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
  <custom-component
  name="myName"
  [isRequired] = true
  ngModel
  ></custom-component>
<button type="submit" (click)="method()">Click</button>
```

The `required` attribute it's initialized correctly in the `<input type="text/>` (wrapped component of `<custom-component>`). The problem is this (it's an Angular problem!): in this code of usage:

```
  method() {
    console.log(this.myForm.valid);
  }
```

The object `myForm.valid` (where `myForm` is associated with `#myForm` in the previous template) return always the `true` value, even if nothing is entered in the text field. This behavior is wrong: I would like this value to be false if I do not insert anything in the required field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add validation to your custom input component you should add the following to your providers:

```
{
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent),
  multi: true
}
```

You will have have to implement the default method, within your InputTextComponent:

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return null;
}
```

If you correctly update a property within your component called **value** using the writeValue() method you implemented with your *NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR* and then ensure to call (you can do this by implementing a change event on your default input):

```
this.propagateChange(this.value);
```

Finally change your isRequired input to the default required property.

```
 @Input() required: boolean;
```

Your NgModel should now correctly update.

**Edit:** To avoid using required (however this is the correct way). Within the validation method place the following code:

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.isRequired && this.value.length === 0 : { required: true } : null;
}
```

What is happening is when Angular runs its own validation it calls this method. When this method returns anything but null, the object is added to the errors property within the FormControl & NgModel.

This is a huge topic and there are some great articles properly explaining it all. However, as asked, this should solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I did everything, except the last step. 
Why I need to edit the input name (@Input() required: boolean;) and how is this reflected in the template of my custom component?

Comment: Ok it works. But what if I wanted to keep the isRequired property?

Comment: I would like to avoid using the "required" property from the caller... I preder use the custom property "isRequired" from the caller

Comment: When using NgModel and ControlValueAccessor, you are informing Angular that you will be treating this component as a default HTML input. You can use isRequired, however, your input element is not the input within the component but your InputTextComponent itself. I will update my answer to include a workaround, however, I would advise against it. That is why using require as you would with a real input is advised.

Answer (score 0):

You should check is form dirty and is it valid. So both needs to be true. Otherwise it shows it hasn't been changed.